# rails nested controller test missing required keys: [:foo_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am writing my first rails app and I am setting up the controller tests. My routes are nested like so:

*config/routes.rb:*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :contacts do
    resources :addresses, :phone_numbers, :emails
  end
  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

The auto-generated tests for the top-level contacts controller are all passing fine. But all of my nested controller routes are erroring. Here is one example:

*test/controllers/phone_numbers_controller_test.rb*

```
  test "should get new" do
    get new_contact_phone_number_url
    assert_response :success
  end
```

*terminal error*

```
Error:
PhoneNumbersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"phone_numbers"}, missing required keys: [:contact_id]
    test/controllers/phone_numbers_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:PhoneNumbersControllerTest>'
```

I realize that the problem is that I am not passing in the contact ID. However, I cannot find a way to do that. I have tried many variations.

Inspired by [Rails 5 testing controller show action, missing required keys: [:id]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262830/rails-5-testing-controller-show-action-missing-required-keys-id) I tried the following, using one of my fixtures:

*test/controllers/phone_numbers_controller_test.rb*

```
test "should get new" do
    contact = contacts(:one)
    get new_contact_phone_number_url(contact)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

but this threw another error:

```
Error:
PhoneNumbersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActionController::MissingExactTemplate: PhoneNumbersController#new is missing a template for request formats: text/html
    test/controllers/phone_numbers_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:PhoneNumbersControllerTest>'
```

I've read through the online rails guides for testing, watched several tutorial videos, but I can't find the answer. I need help with what the syntax is for adding a variable to a nested controller's test.

Here's some other information that may help:

*app/controllers/phone_number_controller.rb:*

```
class PhoneNumbersController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
    @phone_number = PhoneNumber.new
  end
```

*relevant rake route:*

```
new_contact_phone_number GET   /contacts/:contact_id/phone_numbers/new(.:format)    phone_numbers#new
```

*fixtures/contacts.yml*:

```
one:
  salutation: Mr.
  first_name: Jan
  middle_name: M
  last_name: Novak
  ssn: 555-33-4444
  dob: 1999-02-03
  comment: I'm a comment for contact one.
```

*fixtures.phone_numbers.yml*

```
one:
  kind: home
  number: 520-432-1234
  comment: comment for phone number one
  contact: one

two:
  kind: cell
  number: 345-534-2534
  comment: comment for phone number two
  contact: two
```

Thank you very much for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: As you have noticed the scaffolds are not designed to generate code for nested resources, they are really designed for rapid prototyping and to make it so that you need to write less boilerplate code. Some assembly is required. You really fixed the url generation issue all on your own with `new_contact_phone_number_url(contact)`. The fact that you're getting a `ActionController::MissingExactTemplate` is another completely unrelated error. Ensure that the template can be found at `app/views/phone_numbers/new.html.erb`.

Comment: thanks very much @max ! I see now I foolishly never created the view for that method. But once I did, I get the 'undefined variable or method 'contact'' error again. You've already helped me a lot, but if you have any idea why this would come back after fixing the original defining problem, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Its impossible to say anything without seeing the code but my guess is that you're using `contact` instead of the instance variable `@contact` in your view.

Comment: nevermind! It was something simple, I fixed it. Thanks so much for your help in sorting out my thinking on this, as a newbie, I just wasn't looking at the problem the right way.